# Content rollup and display template issue

Tags: 2013, search, html, display-template

I am using this custom display template with a search results web query to roll up tasks. http://www.surfray.com/blog/2013/06/12/aggregate-your-open-tasks-with-sharepoint-2013/

I have followed the instructions as per the blog but when I click on the link to the task it returns me to the home page.  The fault is with the display template ( I think)

The js should construct the url to the list item

```
<a title="Open task" style="cursor:pointer" href="#" onclick="javascript:var domain=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;var title='_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Title=#_';var path='_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Path=#_';if(path.indexOf(domain)===0){SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.dialog.js', null, function () { SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({width: 600, height: 338, allowMaximize: true, title: title, url: path, dialogReturnValueCallback: function (dialogResult, returnValue) { alert('NOTE: Changes to tasks are effective immediately, but will not appear in search results for a few minutes.');SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); }});});}else{var response=confirm('This task is in another domain so it cannot be displayed here due to security restrictions in the browser. Do you want to leave this page to view the task?');if(response===true){window.location.href=path;}}">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Title=#_</a><br />
                <span>Assigned To: _#=ctx.CurrentItem.AssignedTo=#_</span><br />
```

When the item is selected I get the home page and # from href='#'.  How can get the url for the list item ?  Is there a current item parameter?

The display template source is from here http://www.surfray.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Tasks_Custom.rar

Display template and JS newbie so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You mean `ctx.CurrentItem.Path`? It will spit out something like `http://sharepoint/sites/sitecoll/Lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?ID=1`

Why not set the href to `ctx.CurrentItem.Path` instead of #?

Check this out for all the properties you can get: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/06/enumerate-all-properties-of-javascript.html

Comment: Unfortunately ctx.CurrentItem.Path doesn't work.  The URL string is https://site/ctx.CurrentItem.Path

Comment: Is there a value in ctx.CurrentItem.Path?